# Keyboard process Interaction

Tags: io, interrupt-handling

I was wondering what is the step by step sequence of a keyboard interrupt. I know that everytime a key is pressed an interrupt is triggered and the interrupt is queued. If there's no higher priority process the CPU will be allocated to the interrupting process. My question is: where is the interrupting process located in the diagram below (before and after the interruption ). Is it in the ready queue waiting for something to happen or somewhere else ?.

This question was partially answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/719676.

[image]